# Are 'by the time' and 'when' interchangeable?

Tags: phrase-usage

Let's say I am missing my novel and I think that my friend might have taken it after I left the place.

> 1: **By the time I left** my apartment, my friend was still there, so he might have taken it.
>
> 2:**When I left** the apartment, my friend was still there, so he might have taken it.

I know what 2nd expression means, but not so sure about the first expression. Does it convey the same meaning as the 2nd expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, the term *when* points out a specific point in time (when you left the apparment), while the phrase *by the time…* suggests a passage of time that took too long.

So your 2nd sentence (when I left…) better conveys what you are trying to say. The first sentence (by the time I left…) doesn't really convey the correct circumstances of your assertion.

For example:

> The injuries didn't look too serious, but ***by the time*** the ambulance arrived, the victim was dead.
> (Specifies that the delay was at issue)

versus:

> The injuries didn't look too serious, but ***when*** the ambulance arrived, the victim was dead.
> (Still technically correct, but missing the passage of time as an issue)

Sometimes that context is important, so the two phrases are not always interchangeable.

> When you turn on the switch, the light goes on. — ***correct***
>
> By the time you turn on the switch, the light goes on. — ***doesn't make sense***